# Is Linux getting less or more secure?

Tags: passwords, firewalls, man-in-the-middle, virus, antivirus

The famous so-called virus-and-hacker-free Mac is a thing of the past: As it gets more popular it gets more vulnerabilities. Will Linux be the same at some point in time? Is it getting less of more secure?

No computer or network system is 100 percent secure. There is always a vulnerability in every system.

Comment: Afaik it is very hard to say, how secure is something. How do you measure it?

Comment: (Btw, all-capital nicks aren't really loved here - I suggest to use some looking less aggressive.)

Comment: One of the problems we're having in the web server world is that Linux is as secure as the person running it. DIY eCommerce on VPS is quite frightening and it's down to Aptitude Ineptitude (keeping the distro up to date), misconfiguration and failure to patch non-distribution applications.

Comment: It depends upon how you use it.

Comment: [I'm sure I've seen this exact question before.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/692307/is-linux-getting-less-or-more-secure) (turns out it was on another site)

Comment: I broke my Linux box recently so it won't boot, therefore it is more secure

Answer (score 1):

> **Benefits of open-source security**
>
> - More people can inspect the source code to find and fix a possible vulnerability. This can lead to both faster discovery of unintentional
>     security vulnerabilites and prevention of intentional vulnerabilites
>     (backdoors) in the code put there by the developers themselves.
> - Proprietary software forces the user to accept the level of security that the software vendor is willing to deliver and to accept
>     the rate that patches and updates are released.
> - The end-user of open-source code has the ability to change and modify source to implement any extra "features" of security they may
>     wish for a specific use, which can extend to the kernel level if they
>     so wish.
> - It is assumed that any compiler that is used creates code that can be trusted, but it has been demonstrated by Ken Thompson that a
>     compiler can be subverted using an eponymous Thompson hack to create
>     faulty executables that are unwittingly produced by a well-intentioned
>     developer. With access to the source code for the compiler, the
>     developer has at least the ability to discover if there is any
>     mal-intention.
> - Kerckhoffs' principle is based on the idea that an enemy can steal a secure military system and not be able to compromise the
>     information. His ideas were the basis for many modern security
>     practices, and followed that security through obscurity is a bad
>     practice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software_security

Eventually the point is; if I can read it, I can find it. I can find the mistakes and malicious code lines in any kind of computer program "easily". That means open-source is more secure than closed source.

> The development of Linux is one of the most prominent examples of free
>   and open-source software collaboration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux

Comment: Tell me more about how you found heartbleed and shell shock years ago.

Comment: ^^ This appears to be an obvious troll (and a poor attempt) and I feel the need to dispel it. First of all, every statement that @mertyildiran stated is correct. Secondly, Heartbleed had to do with the way TLS was implemented in OpenSSL. Thirdly, while Shell Shock was certainly a serious vulnerability with the way bash handles environment variables, I don't think it can be used solely to say that Linux is becoming "more unsecure" or anything like that. People will always find vulnerabilities in code. With open-source, at least you can quickly get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way to ask this question is, "Are bad guys turning their attention to Linux?" or "Are Linux Threats becoming more common?"  The answer to these questions is certainly yes; there are newly emerging threats to Linux systems, such as [ShellShock](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271), and Linux specific malware variants such as [Linux Banking Trojans](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/cyber-crime/2013/08/linux-bank-trojan-hand-of-thief-debuts/) and [Linux Ransomware](http://techcrunch.com/2015/11/06/linux-ransomware-is-now-attacking-webmasters/) are now being seen.